# Eigenvalues of the Cayley-like graph

Tags: graph-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields

Let $ F_q $ be a finite field of characteristic 2.
Let $ x^2 + Sx +P \in F_q[x] $ be an irreducible polynomial over $ F_q $,
and let $ g $ be one of its roots in $ F_{q^2} $. 
Define a map $ M: F_{q^2}^* \rightarrow F_{q^2}^* $ 
by 
$$  M(c_1 + c_2 g) = c_1 +  c_2 +  c_2 g, $$
where $ c_1  $ and $ c_2 $ are in $ F_q $. 
Consider a directed  graph over the vertex set $ F_{q^2}^* $,
where there is an edge  from $ a $ to $ b $ iff there is
$ \alpha\in F_q $ such that $ b = M( (\alpha +g) a) $.
What are the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the adjacency matrix
of this graph? Note that without M, the graph is just a
Cayley graph  over $ F_{q^2}^* $, thus its eigenvalues and eigenvectors
can be determined easily.

Comment: What is your motivation?

Comment: It comes up in one of my research problems

Comment: Well, yes, I kind of guessed that! The question as presented though seems a bit random (to me, others may well disagree) - it might benefit from some context. Plus the way it arose in your research may help to shed light on how to solve it.

Comment: You are right that it looks random. I have simplified it.